# AutoIt Script to run .exe file

Tags: exe, autoit

I want to run an application which is located in the following directory:

C:\LCR 12\stu.exe

With AutoIt, what would be the code to run the above stu.exe file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
Run("C:\LCR 12\stu.exe")
```

Hope this is what you were after.

Answer (score 2):

You can do by using a variable as below:

```
Local $exeLocation = "C:\LCR 12\stu.exe"
Run($exeLocation)
```